# How can I remove my account?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I accidentally signed up for Moderators Beta - I was just trying to log into another site. How can I delete my account if I no longer want it?

Answer (score 3):

If your account has never voted on Moderators Beta, you can visit your profile on Moderators and select the "Delete" option.

This process is described in the [help center](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account). If you have voted, you'll need to contact the team using the [contact form](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/contact) and select "I need to delete my user profile".